# Jquery height of new DOM element

Tags: jquery, size, element

I'm using jquery to create some new DOM elements. The visualization library I'm using, requires that I pass the size in before the element is added to the DOM.

However, the jquery `width()`/`height()` functions both return 0. Is there any way to compute this size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size depends on styling, so the styling has to be computed. They have to be rendered to be measured. To be rendered they have to be in the DOM (if only for an instant):

- Add them *temporarily* to the DOM (e.g. to body)
- Measure them
- Detach them (until you are ready to add them in their final resting places)

As this all happens in one code/render cycle you will not see the elements.

Comment: @JonathanLam: Read update. You  *have to add them to the DOM to measure them*, but that does not mean they have to be made visible when the page is next rendered to the screen.